# How can I quickly jump to a specific answer when I've posted multiple answers to the same question?

Tags: support, answers, profile-page

It's easy to find a question of mine in my user profile by reading the titles of the questions in the [Questions tab](/users/current?tab=questions). It's similar for answers when I've only posted one answer to a question. I can find them easily in the [Answers tab](/users/current?tab=answers).

However, when I have multiple answers posted to the same question <sup>(which is common on announcements posts, for example)</sup>, it's not easy to find a specific answer because they're all listed with the same title, so I would need to open them one by one. The alternative is to open the question and scroll until the answer is found, which is also not easy because these kinds of posts tend to attract many answers.

**Is there a better way?**

Note that I'm *not* looking for a search solution. I'm aware that I could use something like `user:mine is:a keyword_in_answer`, but there are cases where I might not remember an exact keyword or if I just want to quickly check several answers of mine posted to the same question.

Comment: Note: I just discovered the solution below when I was about to post a [feature-request] to allow expanding answers in the `Answers` tab. I tried looking for a duplicate but I couldn't find one; hence, the self-answer. If someone is aware of a dup-target, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the <kbd>Answers</kbd> tab, you could go to <kbd>All actions</kbd> --> <kbd>Posts</kbd> (or click [here](/users/current?tab=activity&sort=posts)). From there, you can expand each post to quickly identify the target answer(s):

[image: Expanding answers in "All actions > Posts" tab]

The only downside here is that this tab lists both questions and answers and also you don't get to change the sorting like in the <kbd>Answers</kbd> tab.